# Connect firebird remote using PHP

Tags: php, firebird

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and need to connect my page with Firebird remotely, but is not working.
When use the same code with 'localhost' it's OK.

In 123.123.123.12 i'm using my correct address.

```
<?php
$conexao = ibase_connect("123.123.123.12/3050:/var/lib/firebird/2.5/data/database.fdb","SYSDBA","masterkey");
$sql = "INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS (CODCLI,NOME,FANTASIA,CNPJ) values ('99998','Tester','Fantasier','00.000.000/0001-00')";
$resultado = ibase_query($conexao, $sql);
ibase_close($conexao);
?>
```

Comment: "It's not working" is not very helpful... error message?

Comment: Depending on the operating system you can use `netstat` command to check to what IP and port the service is bound to. If its bound to localhost, you would not be able to connect on the IP.

Comment: run this, what do you get? ```<?php
$db = new PDO('firebird:dbname:123.123.123.12/3050:/var/lib/firebird/2.5/data/database.fdb;charset=utf8', 'SYSDBA', 'masterkey', array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));var_dump($db->query("SELECT 1")->fetchAll());
```

Comment: the firebase api is deprecated and [has been removed in PHP 7.4](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration74.removed-extensions.php), use PDO instead. (Firebase access is still available over PDO, it's just the non-PDO firebase api that has been removed.)

Comment: @hanshenrik You mean interbase (the PHP driver for Firebird and InterBase). The driver was removed from main PHP distribution, but is still maintained at https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/php-firebird So it isn't deprecated in that sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, Allow ports using UFW not work alone, after allow ports using iptables work fine.

**USING**:
`iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3050 -j ACCEPT`